# Is data saved with chrome.storage in chrome apps stored in plain text or obfuscated?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have an app that saves data using chrome.storage. I want to know how easy it is to access the data that is stored. I know that the data is not encrypted (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage). But is it obfuscated in any way?

Comment: Why do you care? It's always possible to read it if you really want to. Also, define "obfuscation".

Comment: Obfuscation in this case means if Google applies any kind of obfuscation before storing, to make it harder to access data that an application has stored from outside of the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is directly from the Chrome.Storage API:

"Confidential user information should not be stored! The storage area isn't encrypted."

I understand encrypted isn't obfuscated, but if your intent is to store confidential information. The answer is no.

Which can be found here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage